# reset command over serial connection setting clocal to -clocal

Tags: serial-console, stty

I have a connection from my debian computer to a device with debian linux on it.

If I type the `reset` command on the serial commandline the `clocal` will be set to `-clocal`.

I search the internet why, but I couldn't find out why. The problem is that some commands, like `sudo -i` hang if `-clocal` is set but working if `clocal` is set.

Is there a reason, why reset is setting `-clocal`?

I tried this with picocom, screen, TeraTerm and putty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what `reset` does.
Its manual tells you that it "sets the terminal modes to 'sane' values".
Sanity in this case involves [turning off `CLOCAL`](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/790a85dbd4a81d5f5d8dd02a44d84f01512ef443/progs/reset_cmd.c#L299).

Comment: thx, is there a similar command which does the 'reset' part, but without the 'CLOCAL'?